# bash - export doesn't work

Tags: bash

I'm missing something very elementary. Under Mac OS X. I've tried chmod 0777 setdir.bsh. Must be something wrong with my settings.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                       
export proj=/Users/RParadox/projects/testproject/
echo $proj
```

Result:

```
$ bash setdir.bsh
/Users/RParadox/projects/testproject/
echo $proj
nothing??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` makes the variable available to *subprocesses*, not parent processes.

Can you [source](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html) this file instead ? e.g.

```
$ . setdir.bsh
```

That will execute the file in the current process i.e. the shell itself.

Comment: Doesn't export make the variable available to the _current_ _process_ **and** to the _sub-processes_ ?

Comment: The process that executes "bash setdir.bsh" and the process that executes the bash shell running "setdir.bsh" are two different processes.

Comment: To be clear, export makes the variable available to the process AND child processes, but not parent processes